# css background color composition

Tags: css

I wonder why the rgb value of the section in the middle comes out with (217, 217, 166) [See this color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCNdZ.png).

I can understand for the rest results.

The background color of div whose class is a, which is painted on the right side, comes from this equation.

(0 * 0.5 + 255 * 0.5, 0 * 0.5 + 255 * 0.5, 255 * 0.5 + 255 * 0.5) and with some round-up, it gives us (128, 128, 255).

The background color of div whose class is b, which is painted below, comes from this equation.

(255 * 0.35 + 255 * 0.65, 255 * 0.35 + 255 * 0.65, 0 * 0.35 + 255 * 0.65), and it gives us (255, 255, 166).

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
  </div>
</div>

.a {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}    
.b {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xL73t8qj/

Answer (score 0):

The rgb value of the section in the middle comes out with (217, 217, 166) because of opacity.
As the opacity of the div(with class b) which is at top is set to 0.7. Then it becomes little bit transparent and the div(with class a) is started getting visible.
Both colors get mixed and gave the output as rgb(217, 217, 166).

Answer (score 0):

Well,
if I understand your question correctly, you want to know how to produce (217, 217, 166) from those 2 colors.

- you have the yellow color layer over the blue
- yellow has 70% opacity over the blue layer
- the blue layer has 50% opacity over the white background
- you then need to take yellow (not the one calculated by you, but the (255, 255, 0)) and there you go:

`COLORS   WHITE         BLUE    YELLOW        RESULT 
    R: 255*0,5*0,3 + 0*0,5 + 255*0,7 = 216,75 ~ 217
    G: 255*0,5*0,3 + 0*0,5 + 255*0,7 = 216,75 ~ 217
    B: 255*0,5*0,3 + 255*0,5 + 0*0,7 = 165,75 ~ 166`

Comment: According to the rule i read from [Alpha blending rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/masking.html#SimpleAlphaBlending), the blue color shouldn't be considered when it produces (217, 217, 166)?? Also, then how about the  rest color on the right side, and below? According to your explantion, it should be (255*0.5+0*0.5, 255*0.5+0*0.5, 255*0.5+255*0.5) and (255*0.3
+ 255*0.7, 255*0.3 + 255*0,7, 255*0.3 + 0*0.7)??